# What does "hot module" mean exactlyl from "HMR"?

Tags: webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I am wondering what is an exact unit of "hot module" from "Hot Module Replacement".

I kinda know what "module" means in a general term,

but what is exactly "hot module"?

Thank you.

Comment: Is not “hot module”, the hot refers to the replacement part, as in it happens by itself on the fly

Comment: Then could you tell me what does "module" refer to? Thank you!

Comment: now I got it, Thanks!